# Unable to acess a Function with parameters inside of UseCallback

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, use-effect, usecallback

I have this page (screen) that receives via Params an ID number, in this Screen, I try to call an Action Function from my Action (reducer) file and gets an API call, I thought I didn't get any information in the Array from that call, I believe that the issue was in the Call, but I put a Console log after the declaration on the Action Function, but it didn't print so I think it didn't access to that function, so I believe the issue is in the Call of that function via Dispatch.

I even tried to put a Breakpoint inside the UseEfect where I call the Function that calls the Dispatch Function but it never breaks I'm not sure where is the error, this is the Code:

- Screen (where I suspect the issue is):

  ````
        ```import React, {useState, useCallback, useEffect} from 'react';

        import { ScrollView, Text, Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

        import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

        const ProductDetailScreen = props => {
            const playerId = props.route.params.id;
            const estadId = props.route.params.statId;

            const selectedPlayer = useSelector(state => state.jugadores.availablePlayers.find(prod => prod.id === playerId));


        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
        const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);
        const [error, setError] = useState();

        const goles = useSelector(state => state.jugadores.playerGoals);

        const dispatch = useDispatch();

        const loadEstad = useCallback (async (param) => {
            setError(null);
            setIsRefreshing(true);
            try {
                await dispatch(userActions.fetchEstadistica(param));
            } catch (err){
                setError(err.message);
            }
            setIsRefreshing(false);
        }, [dispatch, setIsLoading, setError]);

        useEffect(() => {       
            setIsLoading(true); 
            loadEstad(estadId).then(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
        }, [dispatch, loadEstad]);

        console.log(estadId);
        console.log(goles);

        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: selectedPlayer.imagen }} />
                <View style={styles.dataContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.description}>Numero: <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{selectedPlayer.numero}</Text></Text>
                    <Text style={styles.description}>Nombre Completo: <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{selectedPlayer.nombre_completo}</Text></Text>
                    <Text style={styles.description}>Posicion: <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{selectedPlayer.posicion}</Text> </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.description}>Edad: <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{selectedPlayer.edad}</Text></Text>
                    <Text style={styles.description}>Nacionalidad: <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{selectedPlayer.nacionalidad}</Text></Text>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
  ````

  ;

  ```
        export const screenOptions = navData => {
            return {
                headerTitle: navData.route.params.nombre,


      }
        };

        const
  ```

  styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
  width: '100%',
  height: 300,
  },
  subtitle: {
  fontSize: 16,
  textAlign: 'justify',
  marginVertical: 20,
  fontWeight:'normal',
  },
  description: {
  fontSize: 16,
  textAlign: 'center',
  marginVertical: 20,
  fontWeight: 'bold',

  ````
            },
            dataContainer:{
                width: '80%',
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginHorizontal: 40,
            },
            actions: {
                marginVertical: 10,
                alignItems: 'center',
            },
        });

        export default ProductDetailScreen

    ;```
  ````
- This is my Action File:

  ````
  import ResultadoEstadistica from '../../models/estadistica/resultadoEstadistica';
  import PlayerEstadistica from '../../models/estadistica/playerEstatisticData';
  import Cards from '../../models/estadistica/cards';
  import Games from '../../models/estadistica/games';
  import Goals from '../../models/estadistica/goals';

  export const SET_JUGADORES = 'SET_JUGADORES';
  export const SET_ESTADISTICA = 'SET_ESTADISTICA';

  export const fetchJugadores = () => {
      return async (dispatch) => {
          //any async code here!!!
          try {
              const response = await fetch(
                  'https://alianzafc2021-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/jugadores.json'
              );

              if (!response.ok) {
                  throw new Error('Algo salio Mal!');
              }

              const resData = await response.json();
              const loadedJugadores = [];

              for (const key in resData) {
                  loadedJugadores.push(
                      new Jugador(
                          key,
                          resData[key].altura,
                          resData[key].apellido,
                          resData[key].edad,
                          resData[key].fecha_nacimiento,
                          resData[key].iso_code,
                          resData[key].imagen,
                          resData[key].lugar_nacimiento,
                          resData[key].nacionalidad,
                          resData[key].nombre_completo,
                          resData[key].nombre_corto,
                          resData[key].nombres,
                          resData[key].numero,
                          resData[key].pais,
                          resData[key].peso,
                          resData[key].player_id,
                          resData[key].posicion
                      )
                  );
              }

              dispatch({ type: SET_JUGADORES, players: loadedJugadores });
          } catch (err) {
              throw err;
          }
      };
  }

  export const fetchEstadistica = player_id => {
      return async (dispatch) => {
          //any async code here!!!
          try {
              const response = await fetch(
                  `https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/players/player/${player_id}.json`,
                  {
                      method: 'GET',
                      headers: {
                          'x-rapidapi-key': Here goes my API KEY,
                          'x-rapidapi-host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
                          'useQueryString': 'true'
                      }
                  }
              );

              if (!response.ok) {
                  throw new Error('Algo salio Mal!');
              }

              const resData = await response.json();
              const loadesApiResult = [];

              console.log('***Impresion desde la accion***');
              console.log(resData);
              console.log('***Fin de Impresionc***');

              //Arrays de la Estadistica del Jugador
              const loadedEstadistica = [];
              const loadedCards = [];
              const loadedGoals = [];
              const loadedGames = [];

              for (const key in resData) {
                  loadesApiResult.push(
                      new ResultadoEstadistica(
                          resData[key].results,
                          resData[key].players
                      )
                  );
              }

              const apiData = loadesApiResult.players;

              for (const key in apiData) {
                  loadedEstadistica.push(
                      new PlayerEstadistica(
                          apiData[key].player_id,
                          apiData[key].player_name,
                          apiData[key].firstname,
                          apiData[key].lastname,
                          apiData[key].number,
                          apiData[key].position,
                          apiData[key].age,
                          apiData[key].birth_date,
                          apiData[key].birth_place,
                          apiData[key].birth_country,
                          apiData[key].nationality,
                          apiData[key].height,
                          apiData[key].weight,
                          apiData[key].injured,
                          apiData[key].rating,
                          apiData[key].team_id,
                          apiData[key].team_name,
                          apiData[key].league_id,
                          apiData[key].league,
                          apiData[key].season,
                          apiData[key].captain,
                          apiData[key].shots,
                          apiData[key].goals,
                          apiData[key].passes,
                          apiData[key].duels,
                          apiData[key].dribbles,
                          apiData[key].fouls,
                          apiData[key].cards,
                          apiData[key].penalty,
                          apiData[key].games,
                          apiData[key].substitutes,
                      )
                  );
              }

              const playerDataGames = loadedEstadistica.games;

              for (const key in playerDataGames) {
                  loadedGames.push(
                      new Games(
                          playerDataGames[key].apperences,
                          playerDataGames[key].minutes_played,
                          playerDataGames[key].lineups
                      )
                  );
              };

              const playerDataGoals = loadedEstadistica.goals;

              for (const key in playerDataGoals) {
                  loadedGoals.push(
                      new Goals(
                          playerDataGoals[key].total,
                          playerDataGoals[key].conceded,
                          playerDataGoals[key].assists,
                          playerDataGoals[key].saves
                      )
                  );
              };

              const playerDataCards = loadedEstadistica.cards;

              for (const key in playerDataCards) {
                  loadedCards.push(
                      new Cards(
                          playerDataCards[key].yellow,
                          playerDataCards[key].yellowred,
                          playerDataCards[key].red
                      )
                  );
              };

              dispatch({ type: SET_ESTADISTICA, estadistica: loadesApiResult, goles: loadedGoals, juegos: loadedGames, tarjetas: loadedCards });
          } catch (err) {
              throw err;
          }
      };
  };```
  ````

Finally this is my Redux Reducer just incase:

```
import { SET_JUGADORES, SET_ESTADISTICA } from "../actions/jugadores";

const initialState = {
    availablePlayers: [],
    estadistica: [],
    playerGoals: [],
    playerCards: [],
    playerGames: [],
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_JUGADORES:
            return {
                ...state,
                availablePlayers: action.players,
            };
        case SET_ESTADISTICA:
            return{
                ...state,
                estadistica: estadistica,
                playerGoals: action.goles,
                playerCards: action.tarjetas,
                playerGames: action.juegos
            };
    }
    return state;
};
```

Sorry for the Format but is giving me some issues; Any Ideas what my Be the Problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a few issues with your `screen` code, so i recommend simplifying the logic to make sure it works before adding anything thing else.

replace this:

```
const loadEstad = useCallback (async (param) => {
          setError(null);
          setIsRefreshing(true);
          try {
              await dispatch(userActions.fetchEstadistica(param));
          } catch (err){
              setError(err.message);
          }
          setIsRefreshing(false);
      }, [dispatch, setIsLoading, setError]);

      useEffect(() => {       
          setIsLoading(true); 
          loadEstad(estadId).then(() => {
              setIsLoading(false);
          });
      }, [dispatch, loadEstad]);

      console.log(estadId);
      console.log(goles);
```

with this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
if (estadId) dispatch(userActions.fetchEstadistica(estadId));
},[estadId]);
```

Assuming your reducer/action code is correct, then this should call the api everytime the params `estadId` changes. The loading/refresh should be set in the reducer instead on the `screen` component.

a few things to keep in mind:

1. Don't await for dispatch.
2. console.log on state variables outside of promise resolving code block won't work.
3. This below won't work. instead, you should set the loading variable as a redux variable that gets updated after the API comes back with data.

   loadEstad(estadId).then(() => {
   setIsLoading(false);
   });

Comment: Thank you for the observation, now I do see it printing correctly, at least on the Actions, I have a new Issue, but it is more to do with working with the Arrays given by the API, maybe you could help me but if not no problems at all:

So the array comes back like this:

Object { 
"API": Object:{
"Players": Array[ 
   Object {
     "age": 31,
        "birth_country": "El Salvador",
        "cards": Object {
          "red": 0,
          "yellow": 0,
          "yellowred": 0,
        },

So what I need to pass to my reducer is CARDS array, any ideas? Sorry

Comment: looks like you can pass that in like so: API.Players[0].cards...

Comment: Hi Wen, 

I know I been bothering you a lot, I'm using the code you mention: 

useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        if (estadId) {
            dispatch(userActions.fetchEstadistica(estadId));;           
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    }, [estadId]);

However as I'm displaying it the first Render gives me undifiend is like it needs to load first to display but even taking it out the dispatch to a Async Function I'm not able to get the code to work the first time (without commenting out the printing part <Text>goles[0].total<Text>). 

Any Idea?

Comment: that's because your API hasn't come back from getting the data yet. All you have to do is do a if statement before returning your view. i.e. if (!data) return null;

Comment: Thank you Wen, that work

I'm so sorry for all the disturbance Thanks

Comment: no worries. I'm glad that worked for you :).